# how can I tell cmake to find Windows Media Foundation?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, ms-media-foundation

To get cmake to link to (for example) `boost::thread` I can write:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
```

and then:

```
target_link_librarie(${target}
    PRIVATE
    Boost::thread
)
```

How do I do this with Windows Media Foundation libraries?

Answer (score 1):

There are three basic ways of handling dependencies with CMake:

CMake ships with a [bunch of find modules for finding external libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-modules.7.html). Your call to `find_package(Boost ...)` is handled by the [`FindBoost`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindBoost.html) module.

Alternatively, your dependency might ship with a [config script](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#config-file-packages) that can be found by `find_package`. This is the approach that is used for finding eg. Qt5.

In your case, unfortunately, none of those apply, which leaves us with the last remaining option: Write your own find script! You can take a look at [the source code for some of the modules that ship with CMake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/tree/master/Modules) as examples. The Boost one is quite complicated, but [FindVulkan](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/FindVulkan.cmake) for instance is reasonably simple.

You mainly need a [`find_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/find_path.html) call for the include path and a [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/find_library.html) call for the `.lib` file. The [MSDN page for the Windows Media Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663600(v=vs.85).aspx) tells you what to search for. If you are lucky, the SDK installer set an environment variable that you can use as a hint for the `find_*` calls, in which case your script will be fully automatic. If not, you will have to manually specify the location when running CMake.

While this approach might seem cumbersome, it is very flexible and allows managing any kind of third-party dependency. If you want to step outside of the realm of pure CMake, you can also take look at package managers like [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) or [conan](https://www.conan.io) for handling dependencies, which offer additional features and comfort.

Comment: I answered my question, because I have a working solution. +1 for the great links and examples!

Answer (score 1):

@ComicSansMS, didn't see WMF on the list. What I did to solve this was the following.

```
set(wmf_libs dxva2.lib evr.lib mf.lib mfplat.lib mfplay.lib mfreadwrite.lib mfuuid.lib)

target_link_libraries(${target}
    PRIVATE
    ${wmf_libs}
)
```

I knew all along that this would do the trick (windows is at least wise enough to know where its own libraries are, so no paths need to be discovered), but I wanted  to know if there is a more CMake-y/stylistically 'correct' way to do it.

Comment: Note that if those libraries are missing for whatever reason, you will end up with a linker error. CMake will not check whether those `.lib` files are already present. That is the advantage of using `find_library` here: CMake will complain during configuration and you get a chance to fix it there before it goes to the build toolchain.